# Expanding Android's ExpandableListView Children above the Group

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

The default behavior of the ExpandableListView implementation is to expand a group's children below the group when clicked.

I'm wondering if it is possible to alter this behavior in order to generate the children above the group (when clicked) by modifying an ExpandableListView XML attribute or programmatically somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up accomplishing this feature set by making a normal ListView and adding a some onClickListeners to show/hide a LinearLayout contained within a RelativeLayout.